# Run Task periodicaly with some exceptions

Tags: android, handler

I need that android application do something ant specific time of the day, for example at 8:00 pm application should log out. I don't want to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) because it fired even if application is not running. also if phone was restarted of turned off schedule dispersers. [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with Runnable will be very nice but if phone go asleep it don't work.
So what i need is:

- Application do something at specified time (which is saved in preferences)
- This should happen only if application is running and logged in (even phone in asleep)

  What can you propose?

EDITED:
Also this task should wait until application ends its other work(sending, receiving data), even better if only executes in specific activity(like home or main where other work aren't performing)

Comment: Strange request, you might want to add more what you are trying to do, because I'm afraid this still seems like a job for an AlarmManager. You can use the boot-intent to reset the alarm, so that objections is invalid. The problem with your proposal is that you need something (a service?) that acts like the alarmmanager, but isn't that alarmmanager. Sounds like more effort then it's worth. Maybe use the manager in place, but check if the app is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to wake the phone up when it is sleeping is by using the AlarmManager. There is no other way (well, you could hold a wake-lock and prevent the phone from going to sleep but that would drain the battery unnecessarily and your users would be angry).

So you want to schedule an alarm using the AlarmManager. Then, when the alarm goes off, you can check yourself if the application is already running and logged in (save this information is some static (ckass) variables). If the application wasn't already running and logged in, then just do nothing.

**EDIT: Add code example**

Create a public static (class) variable that can be accessed by all of the classes in your application:

```
public class Globals {
    public static boolean applicationIsBusyDoingSomethingUseful = false;
}
```

In your application, whenever it is doing something useful and doesn't want to get interrupted or logged-out by your timer-based alarm, it should set this variable to "true" and when it has completed its work and is no longer doing anything useful it should reset the variable to "false":

```
public void someUsefulWork() {
    // set flag while doing useful work
    Globals.applicationIsBusyDoingSomethingUseful = true;
    // do useful work
    // ...
    // end of useful work
    Globals.applicationIsBusyDoingSomethingUseful = false;
}
```

In your BroadcastReceiver, when the alarm goes off you can check if the application is doing anything useful. If it is, you just ignore the alarm and wait for the next one. If it isn't doing anything useful, you log the user out.

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Check if application is doing anything useful
        if (Globals.applicationIsBusyDoingSomethingUseful) {
            // Application is busy working, so ignore this alarm
        } else {
            // Log the user out or whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i can check if application is logged on after alarm go off, but how i suppose to delay log out if some other work is done at that time

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: for example: BroadcastReceiver is registered on manifest.xml. application at current moment send data to server. alarm fired. now BroadcastReceiver is on. it check if user is logged in application now. because it is application should log off it. but only then current task (sending data to server) is ended. how to check from BroadcastReceiver that application is doing?

if i register BroadcastReceiver in activity-onResume() and unregister in activity-onPause() i could miss then application should log off user. how to determine from BroadcastReceiver which activity is in foreground?

Comment: if i somehow determinate that now is running activity, which i cannot interrupt (app communicating with server). how in this case i could delay user log off while communication with server ends)

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to keep track of what the application is doing in a static variable that can be accessed from the BroadcastReceiver, so that it knows whether the application is idle or not. I added a code example to my answer. Hopefully that will make it clear

Comment: I understand and already done this, but how to delay log off then user is doing something useful and alarm fired. in my case if alarm fires i had to log off user is doing something or not. but when app is doing doing something useful it should wait while useful part ends. So **how to delay log off if alarm fires and user is doing something usefull?**

Comment: I don't know your whole application, so it is difficult to say. I guess the alarm receiver could check if the app is doing something useful and if so, it could set another global flag telling the application to log the user off when it has completed the useful work. Or, if the application is doing something useful, it could set another alarm to go off in 1 minute (or 5 minutes or 15 minutes or 1 hour) and then check again if the app is still doing something useful, and continue like this until the user should be logged off. However, why doesn't the app just log the user off when it is done?